# Why is Model Target Generator not starting the training process?

Tags: vuforia

I have used Model Target Generator a few times and it has never given me any trouble. But when I recently tryed to create a new Model Target the application does not start the training process eventhough the database is ready (I can see the set listed at the bottom of the already ready to export sets that i have succesfully trained and used un the past). The original CAD model that I'm using for this Model target has over 2 milion polygons so in the configuration steps I use the simplification option provided by the same applicaiton which gives me a model with 200000 triangles which is clearly inside the limitations specified in the Vuforia documentation. Also I'm using the latest version of Model Target Generator at the moment (v10.14.4).

The problem comes when I want to train the Model Target: I click on the "Train" button, a window displays reminding me how many trainings I have on my account, I click on "Continue" button and the process seems to start but after a few seconds the "Train" button can be clicked again and I receive no indications if the proccess has stopped or there has been an error or is simply doing the training process in the background (I have waited several hours after hitting the "Train" and "Continue" buttons to confirm this last one). I have no clue of what the problem can be since I get no feedback from Model Target Generator. Any insight on the matter is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is an issue with the 3D model data being submitted to the training service.

To pursue further, I suggest that you open a [bug report](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/new/choose) on the Vuforia Engine issue tracker on GitHub.